# Improving g++ output

Tags: c++, g++

g++ sometimes produces pretty convoluted outputs. Specially when dealing with templates. Is there any tool that makes g++ output more readable? ... at least some color?

It may sound silly to ask this question here, but I've been unable to google my way out of this.

Comment: Might be a dupe. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47980/deciphering-c-template-error-messages

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you're free to switch compiler, try [clang++](http://clang.llvm.org/). It's error outputs are most of the time very clear and sometimes it will even tell you what to do to fix your error. You can find a comparison of gcc vs clang error output here: http://clang.llvm.org/diagnostics.html.

Otherwise, as noted by Matteo Italia, look to [STLFilt](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html).

For the color aspect, Edwin Buck's solution ([colorgcc](http://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html)) is very good. You can create symlinks to it named gcc, g++, etc so that it always gets used whenever you run a compiler command (provided you setup the paths in the colorgcc script correctly). I find this especially convenient when compiling some large project from a Makefile. Helps tremendously to detect where exactly something went wrong (especially when you do parallel compilations with `make -j`).

Comment: It's been quite a long time since I asked this question and took your answer. I stumbled upon it while cleaning bookmarks and realized I never commented on the issue. For future reference, I did try clang++ and was most pleasantly surprised by the much cleaner compiler output :) thanks!

Comment: For the color aspect, I find [colout](http://nojhan.github.com/colout/) easier to use and it's g++ theme better looking than colorgcc. It also do syntax coloring within the error messages and its text stream approach permits to color output mixing several commands (like g++ called from a CMake's makefile and filtered with grep).

Comment: Thanks for this. As a bonus, clang colorizes it's output by default (assuming you set the `CXX=clang` in your makefile). Me happy.

Answer (score 44):

GCC as of 4.9 has colourized output ☺

Append the following to your bashrc/zshrc/whatever.

```
export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'
```

Comment: and compile with `-fdiagnostics-color` or `-fdiagnostics-color=ALWAYS` if you're running through a piped build system.

Comment: I think Qix capitalized `ALWAYS` for emphesis, but readers should note that it should be `-fdiagnostics-color=always` or you might get an error saying that ALWAYS is an unrecognized argument and that valid arguments are `always`,  `auto`, and  `never`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me for g++ (compiling through ninja build system)

Answer (score 12):

There's [colorgcc](http://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html), a perl script which wraps the gcc (g++) output with color for easier readability.

As far as the "output" of gcc (g++) I am guessing you're not complaining about the compiled binaries :)

Comment: Uh, interesting, I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 11):

I improve it by using sed to color the output with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read x ; do echo $x ; done \
| sed -e "s/.*error:.*/\x1b[1;36m&\x1b[0m/" \
-e "s/.*warning:.*/\x1b[1;36m&\x1b[0m/" \
-e "s/^\(.*\)\(required from\)/\x1b[1;36m\1\x1b[0mnote: \2/" \
-e "s/^\(.*\)\(In instantiation of\)/\x1b[1;36m\1\x1b[0mnote: \2/" \
-e "s/^\(.*\)\(In member\)/\x1b[1;36m\1\x1b[0mnote: \2/" \
| sed -e "s/error:/\x1b[1;31m&\x1b[1;36m/" \
-e "s/warning:/\x1b[1;35m&\x1b[1;36m/" \
-e "s/note:/\x1b[1;30m&\x1b[0m/"
```

Comment: Sounds interesting, but couldn't get it to work. E.g., `make | colorize` (where `colorize` is your script) was monochrome. How would this be used?

Comment: Use `make |& colorize`

Comment: Oh, colorize script, where have you been all my (professional) life?

Answer (score 6):

If you use gcc 4.9 or higher there are a couple built-in options:

- -fmessage-length=n, which optimizes the output for lines of n characters length.
- -fdiagnostics-color=always, which applies some nice colors. 
  (Works fine on linux, not so much on msys)

For more options and exact usage heres the documentation:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Message-Formatting-Options.html

Answer (score 4):

When dealing with the STL<sup>1</sup>, [STLFilt](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html) comes to the rescue.

On a related note, I also heard that the clang compiler produces by itself much better error messages in general.

---

***Nitpickers' corner***

1. Actually, not the SGI STL, but the parts of it that have been adopted in the C++ standard and are part of the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer your question directly, but note that in regards to templates if you look at the top message (the error caused by the templated) and the bottom "instantiated from here" message, it usually becomes much more clear. Ignore all the middle messages as they are probably not going to help.

Answer (score 1):

There is [colorgcc](https://github.com/johannes/colorgcc).

Answer (score 1):

there is my personal function:

```
colorgcc()
{
perl -wln -M'Term::ANSIColor' -e '
m/not found$/ and print "\e[1;30m$`\e[0m", "$&", "\e[0m"
or
m/found$/ and print "\e[1;30m$`\e[0;32m", "$&", "\e[0m"
or
m/yes$/ and print "\e[1;30m$`\e[0;32m", "$&", "\e[0m"
or
m/no$/ and print "\e[1;30m$`\e[0m", "$&", "\e[0m"
or
m/ Error |error:/i and print "\e[1;91m", "$_", "\e[0m"
or
m/ Warning |warning:/i and print "\e[0;33m", "$_", "\e[0m"
or
m/nsinstall / and print "\e[0;36m", "$_", "\e[0m"
or
m/Linking |link: |\.a\b/ and print "\e[1;36m", "$_", "\e[0m"
or
m/Building|gcc|g++|\bCC\b|\bcc\b/ and print "\e[1;30m", "$_", "\e[0m"
or
print; '
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **GilCC** which is a Ruby tool that will convert GCC output to color in real-time. It is free and you can customize it to your preference. It is not intrusive as it does not change your gcc setup and you don't have to edit any system files such as .bash. You have to install Ruby and be able to invoke Ruby programs from the command line. Right now you have two options Perl script or **GilCC** and if you work with Ruby you will like GilCC.

Then whenever you call "GillCC" it will call "make" behind the scenes with your parameters such as "clean", "debug" or "release". for example if normally you call: "make debug" you should call "GilCC debug".

Almost forgot to mention that **GilCC** has some statistics such as # of warnings and error as well as build time. These things are handy when you are trying to improve your build.

The link to the download page is [here](http://www.onlysolutionssoftware.com/gilcc/).