# how to set gcc output colors for msys2 installation running on windows terminal?

Tags: gcc, colors, msys2, windows-terminal

I've just updated gcc to 13.1 (ucrt version) from the msys2 distribution on windows 10; I use it on the old windows terminal. While compiling I've realized that it gives some hardly distinguishable color in part of the error message (a dark purple on black background). Changing the background color in the terminal doesn't solve, because gcc forces somehow the background color of its output lines to black.

[image]

I've seen on this post :
[Improving g++ output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732562/improving-g-output)
that I can set the colors with the GCC_COLORS variable. But how do I set it from my environment (windows terminal with gcc 13.1 from msys2) ?
I've also tried with a command like this in the windows terminal:

```
setx GCC_COLORS "error=01;30:warning=01;34:note=01;33:caret=01;31:locus=01:quote=01"
```

but it doesn't seem to affect gcc's output.

Please note that:

- I don't want to use clang; this question is about gcc
- I don't want to use powershell; this question is about windows terminal
- I have windows 10, not 11
- I also use linux and compile on it too, but for this question I'm interested in the windows environment.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just pick a different [color scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/color-schemes) in the Terminal settings. Looks like the default "dark magenta on black" contrast just isn't all that good. The built-in "One Half Dark" scheme looks a bit better.

Or if you want to really customize the look, there are TONS of good schemes over at https://github.com/mbadolato/iTerm2-Color-Schemes