# Is there a way to introduce syntax highlighting to gcc/g++'s output?

Tags: gcc, g++

Is there a way to introduce syntax highlighting to the output I get when I am compiling a program with either gcc or g++. Currently its all one colour. I want the colour to change depending on the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has been done as a Perl script [colorgcc](https://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html).

For further discussion:

- [Improving g++ output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732562/improving-g-output)
- [g++, colorgcc and ccache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995415/g-colorgcc-and-ccache)